# USB 1.1 UHCI and root hub on Linux

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver

I have got some very old computer which supports only usb 1.1. There is uhci controller onboard. As far as I know there is no usb-hub built in. The uhci controller has 2 physical usb ports.

But when the linux starts it shows that it recognized 2-ports usb virtual root hub. I'd like to know  if this "root hub" is some kind of abstraction layer for usb-stack? How linux could recognize root hub while there is not such device onboard?

Is this virtual root hub some kind of mapping for those 2 usb ports just for make usb stack easier for programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track with your thinking. There is no separate hub device.

With simplifications: USB architecture distinguishes Host and Device. Within Host there is Host Controller. Yours is of the type [UHCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHCI#Universal_Host_Controller_Interface). Root hub is part of the host controller architecture. Succinct description is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-6960/devusbover-17/index.html). Full precise details may be found in [USB 2.0 specs](http://sdpha2.ucsd.edu/Lab_Equip_Manuals/usb_20.pdf). It may be noted that the root hub abstraction is integral to USB Host specifications, it is not just the linux USB stack that uses this abstraction.

Software such as linux will know how to probe the host controller hardware, it will read registers giving necessary details e.g. how many ports are present.

Some additional good info in top answer [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170128222702/http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070429094719AAMakle).